# windows exessive installation size?

Tags: windows-7, installation

a new Window 7 pro 64 bits instalation took over 40 GB on my SSD.

Properties on what i can see on the system drive accounts for only 11 GB, the trashcan has 4-5 GB allocated, system restore and hibernation are off.

where can the missing 25GB be hidden ?

(this is important as my SSD has only 60 GB, really 55.2 GB usable and i still need to install many programs)

EDIT

As i suspected, it was a standard issue...

it was **pagefile.sys** and **hybernating.sys**

i am searching the net trying to learn how to get rid of them, i though hybernating was off but i was wrong, and i have 16GB ram so the syst attributed 16GB to virtual memory pagefile, i am not sure i need virtual memory, but i may move it to the HDD instead of getting rid of it.

Comment: [Use WinDirStat to see if you can find it](https://windirstat.info/)

Comment: ok, just dowloaded it, will try

Answer (score 1):

When you select all files and show the properties, Windows skips files where your user account don't have **access to** (like System Restore Point data).

Run [TreesizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) **([as admin - very important!!!](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token))** (this shows all folders) and look which folders "eat" most space.

[image]